# How to select the most spanning ranges

Tags: mysql, range

My table looks like

```
+----+------+----+
| Id | from | to |
+----+------+----+
|  1 |    1 | 10 |
|  1 |   10 | 12 |
|  1 |   12 | 23 |
|  1 |   24 | 26 |
|  2 |    2 |  8 |
|  2 |    3 |  4 |
|  2 |    4 | 10 |
+----+------+----+
```

Now I want to group by `Id` and select the most spanning range.
So the result table should look like this:

```
+----+-------------+
| Id |    range    |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | 1-23, 24-26 |
|  2 | 2-10        |
+----+-------------+
```

I do not even know how to start.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Your result seems a bit complicated to achieve in pure SQL. I suggest you to get your result in the application instead, since it has no usage in SQL, only for displaying

Comment: 2 |    2 |  8  is confusing me is the sample data correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct. Why not?

Comment: @dosad why the first record should be `1 | 1-23, 24-26` and not `1 | 1-26` ?

Comment: @Ergest_Basha because it is inclusive

Comment: i'm baffled because in last  3 rows 2- 8 and 3-4 are not contiguous and 2 does not fit into any of the last 2 rows. and 8 only fits into last row.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something similar to this by writing a MySQL select query with the `CONCAT()` function. You can use `GROUP BY` to categorize the data. But keep in mind that `from`,`to` and `range` are reserved words in MySQL. Therefore, I'll use `fooFrom`, `fooRange` and `fooTo` as column name for this example

Example:

```
SELECT Id, CONCAT(fooFrom, "-", fooTo) AS "fooRange" FROM fooTable GROUP BY id;
```

This example code will output:

```
id |  fooRange  
1  |   5-6
2  |  12-88
```

But I'm not sure about how to concat all the content into a one-column value.

Comment: this won't work, there are non aggregated fields in the query